# How to create Index in Field Level by Using NEST Package

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nest, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to create field level indexing in elastic search by using **NETS** package. I am using **.net core** for development.

In this I am having fields *Name*, *Mobile_number*, *app_id*, *address*, *country*.

During the search i am using the fields *Name*, *Mobile_number* and *app_id*. So I need to create index for the above mentioned fields.

I am using the below code to create the index:

```
[ElasticProperty(Store=false, Index=FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]
```

I am getting following errors:

> The type or namespace name 'ElasticPropertyAttribute' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'ElasticProperty' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'Store' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'Index' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 'FieldIndexOption' does not contain a definition for 'not_analyzed'

If it possible i am expecting simple working source code with ui.

How can i create the index for the fields.

Thank you...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use code from an older version of the package, with a newer version of the package. Check out the documentation on Attribute mapping for how to do this with NEST 6.x: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks  Russ Cam.can you give me any working samples.

Comment: There's a working example on the documentation that I've linked to

Answer (score 1):

> *[ElasticProperty(Store=false, Index=FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]*

For `ElasticType`, it has been migrated to `ElasticsearchType`, and for `ElasticProperty`, it has been migrated to specific property like `Date`, `Text` and etc. check [Attribute based mapping](https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch).

Here is a simple demo:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "othername", IdProperty = "MyId")]
public class Foo
{
    [Text(Store = false, Index = true, IndexOptions = IndexOptions.Docs)]
    public Guid MyId { get; set; }
    [Date(Format = "mmddyyyy")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Number(NumberType.Integer, Coerce = true, DocValues = true)]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

One more point, check [[5.0 Breaking Change] String -> Keyword or Text #2384](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2384)

Comment: Thanks Tao Zhou. How to perform CRUD in Elastic Search

Comment: @SATHEESHP Check [Modifying Your Data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/_modifying_your_data.html#_modifying_your_data)